# Cannot complete installing Google Plugin for eclipse

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, eclipse-plugin, google-eclipse-plugin

I am trying to install the Google Plugin in eclipse but I get the follwoing error:

> Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
>   Software being installed: Google Plugin for Eclipse 3.6 1.4.2.v201012211742
>     (com.google.gdt.eclipse.suite.e36.feature.feature.group 1.4.2.v201012211742)
>   Missing requirement: Google Eclipse 3.6 Platform Plugin 1.4.2.v201012211742 (com.google.gdt.eclipse.platform.e36 1.4.2.v201012211742) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.equinox.p2.operations 0.0.0' but it could not be found
>   Cannot satisfy dependency:
>       From: Google Plugin for Eclipse 3.6 1.4.2.v201012211742 (com.google.gdt.eclipse.suite.e36.feature.feature.group 1.4.2.v201012211742)
>   To: com.google.gdt.eclipse.platform.e36 [1.4.2.v201012211742]

Please help

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The App Engine documentation is old, that is the problem. There are newer releases of the API:

- http://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/3.3
- http://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/3.4
- http://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/3.5
- http://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/3.6
- http://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/3.7
- http://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/4.2

Try the one that suits your IDE.

Answer (score 14):

I had the same problem and finally found the solution. Hope it works for you too.
Follow these steps and then try to install the plugin again.

Select Help > Install New Software...
Select the Helios update site in the Work with dropdown. If it's not there, you can enter the URL directly: http://download.eclipse.org/releases/helios
Install Helios > Web, XML, and Java EE Development > Eclipse Web Developer Tools.

Comment: +1 for putting me on the right track. I never got that to work (probably my fault) but I downloaded the "Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers" instead in a hope to get the things mentioned above bundled and that worked.

Comment: I got it working for the current release of eclipse (Juno) by using your instructions and the following URL http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno

Answer (score 5):

Go to About / Install New Software... and enter this URL:  http://download.eclipse.org/mylyn/releases/latest

After the list populates, select MyLyn SDKs and Frameworks  / MyLyn Commons.  Once that plug-in installs, restart Eclipse and then the Google App Engine plug-in should install.

Comment: What a ridiculously broken installation process

Answer (score 2):

When you are on the Available Software screen, after having selected the software you want to install, before you click next, if you check the box "Contact all update sites during install to find required software." then eclipse will automatically resolve and install the needed plugins for you.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error and looking at the messages indicated that it was due to a conflict between Java EE IDE and Google plugin fo different eclipse runtimes ( 3.6 and 3.5).
So I upgraded the Java EE IDE to the latest version available and that solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that [ADT-Bundle](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) whose version is eclipse 4.2 has this issue of installing google plugin and when I downloaded eclipse and [Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) separately and connected them together. It solved the problem. Google plugin installation worked super fine then

Answer (score 0):

Check to see the "type" of Eclipse you are using. I was using the main version of Luna 4.4.2 and having this problem. I then switched to the "Java EE" type of Eclipse, and installed the Google Plugin and AppEngine with no issues. I believe it is because the "Java EE" type comes with WTP.