# GWT installation on Linux

Tags: eclipse, gwt, eclipse-plugin

I am using Redhat linux 32bit version. installed eclipse indigo 32 bit version.

when i tried to install GWT

http://code.google.com/eclipse/docs/download.html

I got the following error message and I am unable to proceed my installation. Kindly help me to overcome this issue buddies.

> Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
>     Software being installed: Google Plugin for Eclipse 3.7 2.5.1.v201201120043-rel-r37 (com.google.gdt.eclipse.suite.e37.feature.feature.group 2.5.1.v201201120043-rel-r37)
>     Missing requirement: Google Plugin for Eclipse 3.7 2.5.1.v201201120043-rel-r37 (com.google.gdt.eclipse.suite.e37.feature.feature.group 2.5.1.v201201120043-rel-r37) requires 'org.eclipse.wst.xml.core 0.0.0' but it could not be found

Comment: Dunno whats the magic., 

Since i need maven I installed 

http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/archived-releases.html

Then tried my luck

by again installing 

http://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/3.7

it got installed 


No error. 


Thank god. mine is work now ... ;) relieved for now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess, you are having the same problem explained here : [Cannot complete installing Google Plugin for eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4672491/cannot-complete-installing-google-plugin-for-eclipse) .
I think this helps.

Comment: Dunno whats the magic., 

Since i need maven I installed 

http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/archived-releases.html

Then tried my luck

by again installing 

http://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/3.7

it got installed 


No error. 


Thank god. mine is work now ... ;) relieved for now...