# Installing Google plugin for Eclipse Helios

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, plugins

I'm trying to install Google plugin for Eclipse Helios. As far as I can see this installation includes `Google App Engine Java SDK 1.6.4`, `Google Plugin for Eclipse 3.7`, `Google Web Toolkit SDK 2.4.0`.

I get the following:

> Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could
>   not be found.   Software being installed: Google Web Toolkit SDK 2.4.0
>   2.4.0.v201203300216-rel-r37 (com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle.e37.feature.feature.group
>   2.4.0.v201203300216-rel-r37)
>   Missing requirement: Google Plugin for Eclipse 3.7 2.5.2.v201203300216-rel-r37
>   (com.google.gdt.eclipse.suite.e37.feature.feature.group
>   2.5.2.v201203300216-rel-r37) requires 'org.eclipse.core.runtime 3.7.0' but it could not be found    Cannot satisfy dependency:
>       From: Google Web Toolkit SDK 2.4.0 2.4.0.v201203300216-rel-r37 (com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle.e37.feature.feature.group
>   2.4.0.v201203300216-rel-r37)
>       To: com.google.gdt.eclipse.suite.e37.feature.feature.group 2.5.2

I tried to install Web Developer Tools (as it was suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4672491/cannot-complete-installing-google-plugin-for-eclipse/4718331#4718331)) and MyLyn Commons (as in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5940585/1240930)), but still get the same error. If I should install another version of the plugin, how can I choose it in the marketplace? And what are the other probable reasons of this message? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To Achieve everything faster, just perform the following:

1. Download the *plugin* manually from its download page
2. Move the *plugin* file(s) to the *plugins* folder of *eclipse*
3. Restart *eclipse*

   - eclipse 4.2 is Juno
   - eclipse 3.7 is Indigo
   - eclipse 3.6 is Helios
   - eclipse 3.5 is Galileo
   - eclipse 3.4 is Ganymede
   - eclipse 3.3 is Europa
   - eclipse 3.2 is Callisto

So, just check for which eclipse version, what GWT plugin version is suitable on the download page.

This will never fail.

Comment: Yeah, first thing I looked at was the name. :)

Comment: And what about possible fails if the version is not the needed one?

Comment: It looks pretty much the same, not a single word about the version.

Comment: And, oh my, it's like I'm commenting by myself. :)

Comment: I moved the files into plugin folder but where is GWT_HOME?

Comment: @QiFan Your comment is irrelevant. The process of installation is described here: https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/install-eclipse-3.7

Answer (score 0):

I tried to install version 3.6 (which appears to be suitable for Helios) manually, with a help of `Install new software...` option and `http://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/3.6` url, and probably it'll work.

Comment: It should work indeed since the plugin version you've indicated in your question was intended to Eclipse Indigo instead of Eclipse Helios

Answer (score 0):

Check this site https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/install-from-zip. You can install the plugin localy.

Comment: Well, the question was about the suitable version of the plugin, not about the possibilities of its installation.