# Can't install Google plugin for eclipse in JUNO

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine

I'm trying to install Google app engine plugin in ADT (eclipse version 4.2 JUNO).
I tried disabling the antivirus and running ADT in administrator. Nothing seems to be working.

Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: Google Plugin for Eclipse 4.2 3.4.2.v201310081840-rel-r42 (com.google.gdt.eclipse.suite.e42.feature.feature.group 3.4.2.v201310081840-rel-r42)
  Missing requirement: Google Plugin for Eclipse 4.2 3.4.2.v201310081840-rel-r42 (com.google.gdt.eclipse.suite.e42.feature.feature.group 3.4.2.v201310081840-rel-r42) requires 'org.eclipse.m2e.core 0.0.0' but it could not be found

EDIT:
I got it WORKING using this answer,
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4718331/2841916

Answer (score 0):

Since ADT-Bundle already brings Eclipse inside i guess it's not necessary for you to configure your Juno Eclipse or less to install it 'cause ADT-BUNDLE it's portable it means it's not necessary to install it!

Here is a video tutorial which i guess will be helpful for you my friend!

http://www.cursopedia.com/Ficha-Curso-de-Android.-Nivel-Basico

Comment: Oh and i forgot to tell u in case u didn't notice: ADT-BUndle comes in a zip file, so , as soon as you unzip it you'll see 3 folders: -Eclipse -SDK -SDKMAnager . In order to startup ADT BUNDLE you're gonna have to enter into eclipse folder and click on the exe!

Comment: I think you didn't understand the question. I know howto use the ADT. I'm trying to use Google app engine. In order to use it I need to install google plugin for eclipse. That's where I faced the issue. anyway thanks.