# All Projects Error after Install Google Plugin on Eclipse Juno

Tags: java, eclipse, google-apps-script

I want to make cloud mobile application and i found Google Plugin for Eclipse, I've installed it on my eclipse Juno but the problem is after I installed it all of my projects went error, for the installation I follow this link tutorial:

https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/install-eclipse-4.2

I search on internet about the issues and I've done these things:

1. downgrade JRE
2. follow these link instructions:

> [Can't install Google plugin for eclipse in JUNO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20087396/cant-install-google-plugin-for-eclipse-in-juno)
>   https://stackoverflow.com/a/4718331/2841916

but the result is still same, can anyone help me?

Comment: Why is this question tagged as google-apps-script?

Answer (score 0):

I just solve my problem
I install the Plugin not from "install new Software" but from "eclipse marketplace", i don't know why this is happen and still don't understand what is the problem, can someone explain it  to me?